# Convert multiple URL to individual PDFs

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, google-docs

Question - I have a Google Sheet with about 200 Google Doc URLS. Is it possible to have a script that will convert the URLS to individual PDF files and save it to my desktop?

I have searched the internet high and low and I cannot find a solution. If anyone has any insight or can point me in the right direction, that  would be really helpful.

Comment: I have 2 questions for understanding your question. 1. What language do you want to use? 2. Can you provide the sample Google Document URLs?

Comment: Sure- So here is the Google sheet with three google DOC uRL examples that I would like converted into PDF. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOJ961BBcjlKEW71ML3hb_bZJDVTAizg12WHLc2AKUI/edit?usp=sharing 

If possible I would like to use Javascript but am open to any suggestions that would save me from having to convert each of the 200 or so doc manually. 

Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be, create a folder inside of Drive, convert the documents to PDFs, and download the folder as a `.zip`.

```js
function convertDocuments() {
  /* Select the Spreadsheet */
  const SS_ID = "SPREADSHEET_ID"
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID)
  const PDF_MIME = "application/pdf"
  const newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('PDFs')
  /* Get the links */
  const getLinks = SS.getRange('A2:A').getValues()
  getLinks.forEach((cells)=>{
    const link = cells[0]
    if(link==="") return
    /* Getting the ID from the URL */
    const parseID = link.toString().split("/")[5]
    /* CREATE THE PDF */
    const document = DriveApp.getFileById(parseID).getAs(PDF_MIME).copyBlob()
    /* Inserting the PDF into the file */
    newFolder.createFile(document)
  })
  Logger.log(newFolder.getUrl())
  /* downloadFolder(newFolder.getId()) */
}
```

The steps are as follows:

1. Retrieve all links inside the `A` column
2. Use `DriveApp` in order to create a PDF for every link (link needs to be parsed for retrieving the ID)
3. Place the PDF inside the Drive Folder
4. From here, you have two possibilities:

   - Use the UI to download the folder
   - Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56312048) function (provided by [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)) to get directly the download link. Inside my script is referenced as `downloadFolder`

```js
function downloadFolder(folderId) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  let blobs = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    blobs.push(files.next().getBlob());
  }
  const zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs, folder.getName() + ".zip");
  const fileId = DriveApp.createFile(zipBlob).getId();
  const url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
  Logger.log(url);
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`getAs(contentType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype)

Comment: When I try to run the first script I am getting the error message 

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.
convertDocuments @ Code.gs:4

Comment: Have you changed the `SPREADSHEET_ID` by your Spreadsheet ID?

Comment: When debugging it stops at the second const      const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID)

Comment: I did and am still getting the same error

Comment: That's strange, the [openById(ID)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) method should not fail. With the example you shared, it should be `const SS_ID = "1mOJ961BBcjlKEW71ML3hb_bZJJDVTAizg12WHLc2AKUI"`.

Comment: My apologies, I had a / that I accidentally included.

Comment: So, the script is working? If so, please, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @Emel- how can I get the function to skip URLS that it cant convert to a PDF? 

Right now, the program stops, I have to debug then find the link and remove it. Then I have to run the program again. 

Is there a way for it to skip over the links it cannot convert?

Comment: You can encapsulate the failing function inside a [`try{}catch{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block.